# SQL dialects translating bridge?

Tags: sql, database, translation

I'm wondering if there are any transparent solutions that would allow me to connect to a server behaving like one database, then once a query is performed, such a server would connect to some predefined third-party SQL server (which uses a different protocol, say, MySQL to Oracle), translate the SQL query to the third party server's dialect, perform it and return translated results. In other words:

1. User connects to the "bridge" and calls a simple DML query using, for example, Oracle's protocol
2. The "bridge" connects to some pre-defined server, translates the query to MySQL's SQL dialect and runs it, then translates the results to Oracle's protocol message and sends back to user

Are there any projects that deliver such functionality?

Comment: So, I just had a great idea for a business venture, assuming no one answers this.

Comment: My guess is that SQL needs semantic decoration of the parse tree in an early stage. The bridge-software wont have access to the catalogs, and thus cannot decorate the tree. Maybe heuristics might help, maybe you can (partially) transform the query without semantic analysis. But it still is a nice idea, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, IBM at least has a product, their [Federation Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/federation-server/).  Of course, it's enterprise-grade, which may be overkill for your particular situation (although it looks like it runs on [pretty much any hardware](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024461)).